# How to obtain input and selected option from pull down menu?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, drop-down-menu

**EDIT!: Silly mistake. I named my button function 'submit'. Javascript thought it was a submit function to handle the form. I changed the function to 'operate' and it works now.**

So my goal is to obtain the user input and obtain the selected option from the drop down menu.
Example - If user selects the 'Find Max' option from drop down menu, I want the main function to call the maxOfTwo function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfunctions.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
function submit() {

        var num1 = parseInt( document.getElementById("num1").value );
        var num2 = parseInt( document.getElementById("num2").value );
        var msg;
        var operation = document.getElementById("operation").value );
        var average = findAvg( num1, num2 );
        var max1 = maxOfTwo( num1, num2 );


        if( operation == Max ) {
            msg = "<div>Option chosen is Find Max" + max1 + "</div>";
}

        else 
        if( operation == Avg ) {
            msg = "<div>Option chosen is Find Average" + average + "</div>"
}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;
```

...

```
Select Operation:<br />
    <class="fstyle"/>

    <select id="operation" class="fstyle">
        <option value="Avg">Find Average</option> 
        <option value="Max">Find Max</option>
    </select><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

.value is a property that will return either "Avg" or "Max" in your code -- it's not a method.
You can also find the selected option's via .selectedIndex and an array of all the options with .options

Comment: But dont I need to set a value for each menu option so JavaScript can determine which function to use?

Comment: In your modified code you have an additional ) after .value -- that should be removed. Other than that, the "if (operation == 'Max')" statement should work fine.

Comment: I removed and it doesn't work. I even used Firebug and no errors were found. It seems that when I click the button, there is no ouput and returns back to first option on drop down menu.

Comment: Do you have a "return false;" statement at the end of your submit function? If you're not stopping the page from submitting it's going to reload the page.

Comment: I do not, let me figure out the right way to apply it and I'll respond back soon. Thanks

Comment: Still couldn't figure it out. I applied the second function in the second file. I'll edit my main post so you can see.